# magento 2: admin login form inputs cut in half

Tags: magento2, admin, css, adminform

I first noticed this bug on chrome canary and now occurs with the latest update to chrome beta.  I have logged it as a bug to chrome, but wanted to get some additional input if this bug is indeed chrome related or is actually magento.

Chrome Version: 55.0.2883.28 beta (64-bit) on Windows 10

[image: default admin loign form inputs]

If I remove the float on .admin__legend, form changes to this

[image: default admin loign form inputs with no float]

It seems that the legend tag's width is unable to be changed, which may be causing the issue and the additional white space inside the legend tag.

Here is what I have tried

[image: element styles applied to admin form inputs]

Ultimately I could solve this with position: absolute; but I feel like that is cheating.

Let me know if you think this is a chrome related issue or something magento needs to prepare to fix.  Also I'd be interested if anyone can come up with a simple fix.

Comment: Use the latest version 2.1.2, if still not display properly, you should open a new issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2

Comment: did a fresh install with magento 2.1.2 and inputs are still cut in half.  Since the browser is beta I will wait a bit more until submitting it as a bug to magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same issue. It's a chrome 55.0 bug. See here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=670837

I fixed the frontend with some quick css and I'm waiting for the v.57.0

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Could you share the CSS you used?

Comment: Updated to 57.0.2954.1 and issue is now resolved